# What categories are described by relational programming languages?

Tags: category-theory, relations, lambda-calculus

I know that lambda calculus is the language of cartesian closed categories.

As I understand it, relational programming systems (that, as the name implies describe a computation in terms of relations) would then operate on those, but also other categories (since functions are a special case of relations).

So what categories do relational databases/languages describe?

Comment: While functions are a special case of relations, the converse is also true: relations are a special case of functions. The two typical ways to express this are: **(1)** to take the *graph* of the relation -- e.g. a binary relation between $X$ and $Y$ can be identified with a subset of $X \times Y$, which in turn is a monic map with codomain $X \times Y$; **(2)** as a function whose codomain consists of truth values.

Comment: Adding to @Hurkyl's comment, a relation between $X$ and $Y$ is the same as a function $X \to 2^Y$, so the category Rel of relations is the Kleisli category of the powerset monad on Set. Also perhaps more interestingly, Rel is a model for linear logic, see e.g. http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~schalk/notes/llmodel.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relational languages may be described by *allegories*.

$$\textbf{Relations are to allegories as functions are to categories.}$$

An allegory is a category where the arrows are considered to be *(some form of abstract) relation* and are endowed with the notions one expects of relations: Converse, an order, and intersection --to name a few.

An allegory can be thought of a a middle ground between a category and a topos.

As your remark points out, the arrows --i.e., *relations*-- in an allegory that are *functional*, in nearly the same way as in set theory, form a category themselves.

Comment: It may be worth clarifying that "relation" as used in this post refers specifically to binary relations.